# UWP MasterDetailsView DetailsView Back to MasterView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

How can I let my `DetailsView` go back to `MasterView` when `MasterDetailsView` is in the Compact Mode?

I don't want to use the given back button so I set `BackButtonBehavior="Manual"`. But how can I control the back behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MasterDetailsView` in the Windows Community Toolkit does not provide methods or properties to change the state of the current display.

Currently you can only get the `ViewState`, but you cannot change it. If you need a custom navigation fallback, you can create your own [Mater/Detail view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/master-details)

Best regards.

Comment: Because there is a `manual` option for the `BackButtonBehavior`, I thought this would be possible...

Comment: Yes, `MasterDetailsView` does provide this property, but this is a Bad Design, which does not provide a corresponding method implementation.